# Tensorflow not compiled using GPU

Tags: tensorflow

My OS is 64-bit Windows 10 and I just installed the GPU-support version of tensorflow using Anaconda. When I try to run it , I got some errors:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
2018-05-21 19:35:51.322771: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-05-21 19:35:55.372582: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
2018-05-21 19:35:55.414069: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-IGTS77R
2018-05-21 19:35:55.440073: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: DESKTOP-IGTS77R
Device mapping: no known devices.
2018-05-21 19:35:55.454801: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:284] Device mapping:
```

How do I fixed the errors? I have installed CUDA9.0 and CUDNN7.0 and my python version is 3.6.

Comment: Which hardware are you using? Also, does your system detect it? And have you checked if you are using a compatible driver?